# Jquery maintain table column count of 10 move columns to new table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a dynamic html table that is being printed and need to maintain a column count of 10 to avoid truncation. I was trying to limit the column count to 10 and move any columns above that to a new table then append the new table to a div (`id="divTtableContainer"`).

I also need to maintain all the attributes associated with the TR and TD elements. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Example:
For simplicity I reduced the number of columns to 2 in this example.

```
<div id="divTtableContainer">
<table id="tblFlowsheet">
<tr>
<td class="header">1</td>
<td class="header">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="Data">1</td>
<td class="Data">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="Data">1</td>
<td class="Data">2</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

The end result would be as follows

<div id="divTtableContainer">
<table id="tblFlowsheet_2">
<tr>
<td class="header">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="Data">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="Data">1</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table id="tblFlowsheet_2">
<tr>
<td class="header">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="Data">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="Data">2</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div>
```

Comment: Could you add some code along with a jsFiddle. It is a bit difficult to understand what exactly you want with the current question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a good start :

http://jsfiddle.net/XxqRK/1/

The main trick here is : `.append($('>:gt('+limit+')',this));`. Basicly, it takes the `td` greater after the two firsts (for `limit = 1`) of the row and moves them to the new one.

Change the `limit = 1` to `limit = 9` to limit to 10 columns. Here, the new created table is inserted just after the other.

Comment: @DanCodispoti tell your boss this is not a way to treat people !